# Play! Extending play.data.Form

Tags: java, inheritance, playframework, playframework-2.1

I am trying to extend play.data.Form in Play 2.1 to add this method:

```
public List<ValidationError> fieldErrors()
```

This is because in some pages I want to just combine all field errors added by play.data.validation.Constraints at the top/bottom of page.

Has anybody extended play.data.Form? I am having trouble because the bindForRequest() method seems to return a new Form() instead of populating the existing object, which is making sub-classing non-trivial.
Play code here: https://github.com/playframework/playframework/blob/master/framework/src/play-java/src/main/java/play/data/Form.java#L306

Maybe I am doing this wrong?

Comment: Is `form.errors()` not enough?

Comment: That returns a Map<String,List>. I need the length of the error list before iteration for UI tweaking and I was hoping to avoid complexity in view so that I could simplify usage across templates.

Comment: Subclassing `Form` will be quite a task just to add one function and still have the other functions return your subclass. Wouldn't it be better to make some sort of helper function to transform the `Map<String, List>` into the structure you want to pass to the view?

Comment: Yeah, that seems to be the best way. I will add that to my helper class. Thanks!